# visual studio 2008 with crystal reports latest run time - is it possible?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Is it possible to build reports using the latest run-time for crystal reports(CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_9.msi)  using visual studio 2008?  or do I have to use the crystal reports for visual studio 2008?  and if that is the case how can i deploy it out to a server that only has the latest crystal reports runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ludek Uher's answer to Dorel Vrinceanu's question [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2013/06/28/how-do-you-spell-confussion-cr-for-vs-crystal-2011-bi-4x-and-the-net-sdks), I don't think it is possible to work in Visual Studio 2008 with 13.x file version of Crystal Reports.